# Javascript change link color bug?

Tags: javascript

My code is:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:if(document.body.style.backgroundColor!='#000000'){document.body.style.backgroundColor='#000000';}else{alert('test');}">linkhere</a>
```

If I paste this into jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/ey7Lv/) and run it does not show the alert on the second click.  But I can see nothing wrong with the code.

What am I doing wrong here?

update with RGB: http://jsfiddle.net/ey7Lv/16/  Still not activating the alert on second click.

Comment: try `rgb(0, 0, 0)` instead of `#000000`

Comment: It's because your browser returns `document.body.style.backgroundColor` as RGB instead of hex.

Comment: problem resolve http://jsfiddle.net/xzvDF/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From memory, the browser can represent the colour in a number of different ways.
You may tell it to set the colout to #000000, which it may then store as 'black' or rgb(0,0,0)

Using Chromium, if I change the two instances of '#000000' to 'black', it works.

So, your updated code would then be:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:if(document.body.style.backgroundColor!='black'){document.body.style.backgroundColor='black';}else{alert('test');}">linkhere</a>
```

Of course, the other thing you could do would be to alert the current colour before you set it.
I.e

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:if(document.body.style.backgroundColor!='black'){alert(document.body.style.backgroundColor);document.body.style.backgroundColor='black';}else{alert('test');}">linkhere</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:if(document.body.style.backgroundColor!='black'){document.body.style.backgroundColor='black';}else{alert('test');}">linkhere</a>
```